# What are the alternatives for "May I ask..."

Tags: phrases

Before posting a question, "May I ask..." seems would make it more politely. I wonder what are the alternatives for that phrase? Seems "Pray, .." also do, but that sounds a bit Jane Austin?

Comment: Maybe "Excuse me, but could I..."?

Comment: @DogLover Seems reasonable as an answer to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really, there are very few. The best alternative would probably be:

> Excuse me, but could I...?

Or maybe:

> ..., if you don't mind me asking?

In context:

> 'Excuse me, but could I please have your date of birth?'
>
> 'What kind of car do you drive, if you don't mind me asking?'